# WSO2: is it possible to customize error message ? {"error_description":"Client Authentication failed.","error":"invalid_client"}

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2

I am trying to customize an error message I am getting after request missing Authorization Header:

```
curl -k -X POST https://localhost:8243/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Currently the response looks like:

```
{"error_description":"Client Authentication failed.","error":"invalid_client"}
```

Is it possible to customize the error message above?
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is coming from the token endpoint. So not possible to change these errors. https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/2ab197fa63b036fc2a0d776a2fc85199901f0fb6/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/endpoint/token/OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java#L231

Comment: As a workaround, you can change the `_Token_API.xml`  file to identify the missing header in the InSequence and store as a boolean property. In the outSequence, check for the property value and alter the error message as you wish.